# JavaScript Object Transformation

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects and 2 arrays to make comparison from. Based on the comparison of the elements in the array and keys in object the object needs to be transformed into a new object.

For example

The original object is as follows

```
[{
'Period 1': 1000.00
'Period 2': 2500.00
'Period 3': 1500.00
'Product': 'ABC'
},
{
'Period 1': 3000.00
'Period 2': 1500.00
'Period 3': 2500.00
'Product': 'XYZ'
}]
```

The arrays are as follows

```
var arr1 = ['Product']
var arr2 = ['Period 1','Period 2','Period 3']
```

The expected result based on the comparision from the above array in the object must be as follows

```
[
{
'name': 'ABC'
'data': [1000.00,2500.00,1500.00]
},
{
'name': 'XYZ'
'data': [3000.00,1500.00,2500.00]
}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code in the question, and a demo to reproduce your particular issue.

Comment: The keys `P1` etc. in `arr2` do not match the keys in the original object.

Comment: I'd suggest using `map` at the high level to transform each of the objects in the input array into an object, whose `name` property will be set based on `arr1` and the `data` property set using a `map` on `arr2` to transform the property names there into the relevant value from the object. If you don't know `map`, please stop everything else you are doing and study up.  By the way, is `arr1` supposed to contain only one element; what is the desired behavior if it contains more? Meanwhile, you could take this question down before downvotes hurt your reputation.

Comment: @torazaburo; arr1 is going to contain only 1 element. Actually, I noticed it and converted it to a simple string instead of an array.

Comment: @torazaburo; If its is not asking too much then could you help me with a code sample of some sort. Thanks!

Comment: No, I couldn't. SO is not a free code-writing service, notwithstanding what some posters and responders seem to think.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used something like below to achieve the type of object required

```
var finalArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var tempArr = [];
    var tempObj = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        tempArr.push(parseFloat(obj[i][arr2[j]]))
    }
    tempObj.name = obj[i][arr1];
    tempObj.data = tempArr;
    finalArr.push(dataTemp);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code :

hope helps.

```
var ori = [{
'Period 1': 1000.00,
'Period 2': 2500.00,
'Period 3': 1500.00,
'Product': 'ABC'
},
{
'Period 1': 3000.00,
'Period 2': 1500.00,
'Period 3': 2500.00,
'Product': 'XYZ'
}];

function oriVal(prop){
var arr = new Array();
for(var i = 0;i < ori.length; i++){
for(var p in ori[i]){
if(p == prop){arr.push(ori[i][p]);}
}
}
return arr;
}

Array.prototype.pushRange = function(arr){
for(var i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
this.push(arr[i]);
}
}

function formName(keyArr){
var retArr = formArr(keyArr);
return {name:retArr.join(',')};
}

function formData(keyArr){
var retArr = formArr(keyArr);
return {data:retArr.join(',')};
}

function formArr(keyArr){
var retArr = new Array();
for(var i = 0;i < keyArr.length;i++){
var oArr = oriVal(keyArr[i]);
retArr.pushRange(oArr);
}
return retArr;
}

function nameData(){
var nameObj = formName(["Product"]);
var dataObj = formData(['Period 1','Period 2','Period 3']);
return {name:nameObj['name'],data:dataObj['data']};
}

console.log(nameData());
```